# javascript / jquery block text on entering input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible for javascript / jquery / html / css / something else to block all text inside input field upon entering the said field?

It sounds like n00b question, but I can't find the answer >_<

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `block all text` ?

Comment: It does not sound like a n00b question, it is just not clear like others suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the `disabled` attribute which you can add with javascript once the `blur` event of the input has fired?

```
$("input[type=text]").blur(function(){
    if($(this).val().length){
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
});
```

Should do the trick (not tested, but should work).

Comment: no. I just want to block the text upon focus, so the default value should be easily removed (by pressing delete or backspace) if the user doesn't want the default value. thx anyway

Comment: Do you mean 'select' rather than 'block' by any chance?

Comment: LOL. that's explain why I couldn't google it. In my country, we called it 'block' not 'select'. thx lol